# I want to find out header name in MS Excel on the basis of starting value of each row

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want to find out header name on the basis of starting value of each rows.

For Example:
As per below screenshot, the start point value in row 2 is from column G then in Column N the formula should retrieve 2028 as the header name.

[image: Screenshot]

Thanks for your help in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### First Occurrence of a Non-Zero Value in a Row

**Excel (Structured) Table**

- In an Excel table, spilling formulas don't work.
- In an Excel table, all headers are strings.
- It is assumed that the years are in ascending order and in consecutive columns and are the only numeric headers. They can be located 'anywhere' in the table's headers.
- Adjust the table name.
- Best clear the contents of the `Year` column before entering the formula into its first row. The remaining rows and any newly added rows will get populated automatically.

```
=LET(h,Table1[#Headers],d,Table1[@],ne,0,nf,"No",
    nh,IFERROR(--h,""),iMin,XMATCH(MIN(nh),nh),
    iMax,XMATCH(MAX(nh),nh),s,SEQUENCE(,iMax-iMin+1,iMin),
    hd,INDEX(nh,,s),dd,INDEX(d,,s),
TAKE(FILTER(hd,dd<>ne,nf),,1))
```

[image]

**Table Range**

- The following formula in `M10` spills down to `M14`.

```
=LET(Data,B9:L14,ne,0,nf,"No",
    h,TAKE(Data,1),d,DROP(Data,1),
BYROW(d,LAMBDA(r,TAKE(FILTER(h,r<>ne,nf),,1))))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try `FILTER()` function.

```
=INDEX(FILTER($B$1:$G$1,B2:G2>0),1,1)
```

For dynamic spill array-

```
=BYROW(B2:G5,LAMBDA(x,INDEX(FILTER($B$1:$G$1,x>0),1,1)))
```

[image]